# Python optimizing the cose using cProfile

Tags: python, optimization

```
def create_file_numbers_old(filename, size):
    start = time.clock()
    value = 0
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        while f.tell()< size:
            f.write((str(value))+'\n')
            value += 1

    end = time.clock()
    print "time taken to write a file of size", size, " is ", (end -start), "seconds \n"
```

This is the function i need to optimize! Can someone help me to run it in around 3-4 seconds?

```
def main(argv = sys.argv):
    #add argument checking and parsing here ..

    fpath = output_path(r"est.txt")
    size=50*1024*1024      #write a 50M file
    cProfile.run("create_file_numbers_old('%s', %d)" %(fpath, size))
    fpath1 = output_path(r"est1.txt")
    cProfile.run("create_file_numbers_new('%s', %d)" %(fpath1, size))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You can't really optimise a lot about I/O, there's just a lower bound on how long writing 50MB will take. I would however consider reducing the number of `write()` calls. Write more than one value at once, then truncate it when you overshoot the limit. You can test whether this will work by comparing how long it takes to write 50MB of dummy data in ~8 byte increments, and writing out the whole string at once. (By only timing the `write()`)

Comment: Also, your indentation is clearly broken, you should check your code sample. The preview feature is your friend. And last but not least, "in around 3-4 seconds" isn't useful to anyone else. If your code is IO-bound (which is likely), it will probably already run a lot faster for anyone with a SSD.

Comment: You could create the buffer in memory and then write the whole thing at once, but it's already gonna be buffered for you to some degree.  I think the `while` loop can probably be optimized out

Comment: And FWIW, I'm not sure if profiling is of much use for use cases like this when your algorithm is trivial. Here you'll clearly be spending all your time inside `write()` and incrementing `value()`, it won't really tell you what to focus on. Profiling serves for improving the performance of more complex code where you need to find out which part of it is slow. It doesn't tell you *why* that code is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the call to `.tell()` slows things down significantly for me.  If you keep track of how much has been written in python-space, you can cut down the time by a factor of 10.

```
def create_file_numbers_old(filename, size):
    start = time.clock()
    value = 0
    written = 0 # number of bytes written so far
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        while written < size:
            s = str(value) + '\n'
            written += len(s) # add how many bytes are in this write() 
            f.write(s)
            value += 1

    end = time.clock()
    print "time taken to write a file of size", size, " is ", (end -start), "seconds \n"
```